# Points can be approximated dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: number-theory, approximation, rational-numbers

> Let $A_n$ be such a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that for any $\epsilon>0$, if $x\in A_n$ then $x\in (\frac{p}{q}-\frac{\epsilon}{q^n}, \frac{p}{q}+\frac{\epsilon}{q^n})$ for some rational $\frac{p}{q}, \text{gcd}(p,q)=1$.
>
> Prove that $\cap_n A_n-\mathbb{Q}$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm wondering if Dirichlet's approximation theorem helps here, and I have tried to prove $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \delta>0$, there exists a number in $\cap_n A_n-\mathbb{Q}$ in $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$, but I can only prove this for $x\in \mathbb{Q}$. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please, write it in a more formal way. I didn't understand.

Comment: @Tancredi where you can't understand?

Comment: Perhaps it's my fault, but I don't get the $A_n$ definition

Comment: @Tancredi I've edited it. Does it makes clearer now?

Comment: I still don't get it. What if $A_n=\emptyset$?

Comment: @Tancredi I mean that if define $A_{n,\epsilon}=\cup_{p/q\in \mathbb{Q}} (p/q-\epsilon /q^n, p/q+\epsilon /q^n)$, then $A_n=\cap_{\epsilon >0} A_{n,\epsilon}$.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't mean to be rude, it was just to better understand. I'll thinking about that :)

Comment: @Tancredi Thanks, it seems this really need careful definition :)

Comment: Why cant $A_n$ simply be $\mathbb{Q}$, in which case $A_n \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is empty (and very much not dense)?